# Sum of n independent F distribution random variables

Tags: pr.probability

I need a help:

What will be the distribution of sum of $n$ independent F distributed random variables with parameters 1 and 1 (i.e., $F(x;1,1)$?

Formally, say $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are i.i.d. as F(1,1), what is the distribution of $\sum x_i$?

Great if you can suggest some references too, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is a closed form in general.  The characteristic function of one of your random variables is, according to Maple, ${{\rm e}^{-is}}{\rm erfc} \left( \sqrt {-is} \right)$, so the characteristic function of your sum is
${{\rm e}^{-ins} }{\rm erfc} \left( \sqrt {-is} \right)^n$.
For $n=2$ the PDF for $x > 0$ is
$$ \dfrac{2}{\pi (2+x)\sqrt{1+x}} $$
For $n=3$ it is
$${\frac {2}{{\pi }^{2} \left( 3+x \right) \sqrt {2+x}} \left( 
\arctan \left({\frac {{x}^{2}+2\,x-1}{2\;\sqrt {2x+x^2}}}
 \right) -\arctan \left( {\frac {1}{\sqrt {2x+x^2}}} \right) +
\pi  \right) }
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is good enough for me. Just one more question, how do you get the pdf? (e.g., by Maple?)

Comment: Yes, using Maple.